# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application $ApplicationClass$ ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, classnotfoundexception, dagger-hilt

I have created an app with compose, I have used hilt. However, I have got this fatal error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.example.stockmarketapp, PID: 13269
                                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.example.stockmarketapp.StockApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.stockmarketapp.StockApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~o30bU7nyuY245CegeM3Z4w==/com.example.stockmarketapp-A-XrWTo_D8jU9CrU9oqFdA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~o30bU7nyuY245CegeM3Z4w==/com.example.stockmarketapp-A-XrWTo_D8jU9CrU9oqFdA==/lib/arm, /system/lib, /system/system_ext/lib]]
                                                                                                        
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.stockmarketapp.StockApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~o30bU7nyuY245CegeM3Z4w==/com.example.stockmarketapp-A-XrWTo_D8jU9CrU9oqFdA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~o30bU7nyuY245CegeM3Z4w==/com.example.stockmarketapp-A-XrWTo_D8jU9CrU9oqFdA==/lib/arm, /system/lib, /system/system_ext/lib]]

Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/example/stockmarketapp/Hilt_StockApplication;
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                ... 17 more
```

I try to start main activity with @AndroidEntryPoint annotation, I have Application class -

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class StockApplication: Application() {
}
```

This is the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.stockmarketapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:name="com.example.stockmarketapp.StockApplication"
        android:required="false"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.StockMarketApp"
        tools:targetApi="31"
        tools:ignore="MissingClass">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.StockMarketApp">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is the Main Activity:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            StockMarketAppTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                    Greeting("Android")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here are versions and plugins:

```
 ext {
        compose_version = '1.2.0'
        hilt_version = '2.45'
        kotlin_version = '1.0.0'
    }
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
    id 'com.google.devtools.ksp' version '1.7.0-1.0.6'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'

//Dagger - Hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:$hilt_version"   //annotationProcessor
    implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03'
    kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0'

}
```

I have this block too:

```
kapt {
    correctErrorTypes true
}
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

In your AndroidManifest.xml try to write like this

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<application
        android:name=".StockApplication"

>
</application>
</manifest>
```

which means remove the package name in the manifest tag and for the android:name in application tag do not use the full package name.